# What is the PySpin equivalent of the PyCapture2 camera Power ON function/method?

Tags: python-3.x, flycapture, pyspin

I am searching for a method to test if the camera is on for PTG camera.

In PyCapture2 the below code works but the presumed PySpin `cam.DeviceConnectionStatus()` will not work because the function seems not to be present.

*PySpin Camera library version: 1.23.0.27*

The Error:

> Error: Spinnaker: GenICam::AccessException= Feature not present (reference not valid) : AccessException thrown (file 'IEnumerationT.h', line 341) [-2006]
>   (False, SpinnakerException("Spinnaker: GenICam::AccessException= Feature not present (reference not valid) : AccessException thrown (file 'IEnumerationT.h', line 341) [-2006]"))

I've tried also `PySpin.Camera.DeviceConnectionStatus()` but it gives the following error whether prior or after `cam.Init()`:

> ```py
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "X.py", line 82, in YZ
>     print (PySpin.Camera.DeviceConnectionStatus())
> TypeError: 'property' object is not callable
> ```

Working PyCapture2 code:

```py
    def cameraOn(self, cam):

        # Power on the Camera
        cameraPower = 0x610
        powerVal = 0x80000000

        cam.writeRegister(cameraPower, powerVal)

        # Waiting for camera to power up
        retries = 10
        timeToSleep = 0.1    #seconds
        for i in range(retries):
            sleep(timeToSleep)
            try:
                regVal = cam.readRegister(cameraPower)
            except PyCapture2.Fc2error:    # Camera might not respond to register reads during powerup.
                pass
            awake = True
            if regVal == powerVal:
                break
            awake = False
        if not awake:
            print ("Could not wake Camera. Exiting...")
            exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems there is an `IsValid()` function available from the `CameraBase()` class in the PySpin/Spinnaker library. This function returns either the bool **`True`** once a connection could be made, communication was successful and the camera is still valid for use or a **`"False"`** respectively. However, this function does not turn the camera **ON** or **OFF**. Nor does it power from a sleep/wake state.

For unknown reasings the `IsValid()` function does not report back tracebacks for logging or debug purpose. So keep in mind to implement try/except for certain methods.

```
try:
    ... your code ...

except PySpin.SpinnakerException as error:
            print('Error: %s' % error)
            return False, error
```